# Generate random item from list Excel 2003

Tags: list, random, excel-2003

I have a list of names in cells A1:A100, and I'm looking for a formula to enter into a cell that will select a random name from that range. I have spent much time searching to no avail, all solutions seem to be derived from the RANDBETWEEN function which is not part of Excel 2003, but only newer versions. This seems like a very common thing to want to do so I'm really surprised there is no easy-to-find solution. Help is much appreciated =)

Comment: Have you tried the options mentioned here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2768-excel-select-random-names.html ... this problem seems very well-covered from just a quick Google search.

Comment: Yes of course, that solution uses RANDBETWEEN function, Excel 2003 has no RANDBETWEEN function, that solution does not work therefore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use RandBetween(), you can still use Rand(), which delivers a decimal number. Round the decimal number to 2 places, then multiply by 100 to get a number between 0 and 99. Add 1 to get a number between 1 and 100

```
=(ROUND(RAND(),2)*100)+1
```

Feed that into an Index function like this

```
=Index(A1:A100,(ROUND(RAND(),2)*100)+1)
```

Done.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Teylyn. That was the last thing I needed to know for my project =)